# Rebuild cache (varnish/redis) after clearing?

Tags: full-page-cache, varnish, redis, caching

I have my shops set up with Varnish and Redis, that all works great. It's fast, responsive. But after clearing the caches (i.e. after updating repositories and what not), every first load of every page is slow. The second time I open that page, it's lightning fast again.

Of course, this is because the cache has been updated after visiting that page. Is it possible to rebuild the cache for all pages on my shop, without manually clicking every product or relying on visitors to open all the pages?

I'm thinking maybe something as a crawler that requests every page in the sitemap or something. I can't seem to find anything about this online. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You need a cache warmer to keep your cache warm, and toasty.

Comment: A cache warmer..! Thanks! I couldn't have thought of that term myself. Googling this I see there are many options available, thanks!!